# Heap and PermGenspace increase in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory

I see that tons of questions posted in SO and other sites to increase tomcat memory when outoferror occurs. But none of them looks the same because some of them said use `CATALINA_OPTS` and some said `JAVA_OPTS`. and the location mostly they said like `bin/setenv.sh` if no file created it.

I follow the above things and still could not set the `memory` correctly as expected.

I have created the `setenv.sh` file inside bin directory of currently using tomcat.But still heap space is not increased.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

this is my content of setenv.sh and please anyone explain what is the problem here, and whether `set` or `export` need to use in setenv.sh.

Can any one guide me for this?

Comment: All you have to check is what all parameters you are passing to your `java` command.

Comment: Use `export`, otherwise the environment variable setting will not be seen by the calling shell.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to edit the bin/setenv.sh

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

`JAVA_OPTS` is passed to all JVM processes running on the same machine.

Use `CATALINA_OPTS` if you specifically want to pass JVM arguments to Tomcat.

By using the `ps -eaf | grep 'tomcat'` in the terminal, we can confirm the values.

Eg.,

```
root     32451     1 99 13:57 pts/1    00:00:07 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties  
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat 
-Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i confirm the New HeapSize i set?

Comment: I have added the steps to confirm the values.